# Marker image in google maps depending on column value

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found a script that makes it possible to create markers in google maps. The markers are loaded from a database. A part of the script is as follows:

```
    //Load Markers from the XML File, Check (map_process.php)
        $.get("map_process.php", function (data) {
            $(data).find("marker").each(function () {
                  var name      = $(this).attr('name');
                  var address   = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('address') +'</p>';
                  var type      = $(this).attr('type');
                  var door      = $(this).attr('door');
                  var point     = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('lat')),parseFloat($(this).attr('lng')));
                  create_marker(point, name, address, false, false, false, "http://www.example.com/marker/icons/A.png");
            });
        });
```

I made it possible to select 3 'types' by creating a marker, for example A, B and C. All the markers are now displayed by A.png. I was wondering if it is possible to make the marker image depending on the type. If type is A, than A.png, if B, than B.png and if type is C, than C.png.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some `if statements`?

```
//Load Markers from the XML File, Check (map_process.php)
        $.get("map_process.php", function (data) {
            $(data).find("marker").each(function () {
                  var name      = $(this).attr('name');
                  var address   = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('address') +'</p>';
                  var type      = $(this).attr('type');
                  var door      = $(this).attr('door');
                  var point     = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('lat')),parseFloat($(this).attr('lng')));
               if(type == "A"){
                 create_marker(point, name, address, false, false, false, "http://www.example.com/marker/icons/A.png");
               } else if(type ="B"){
                 create_marker(point, name, address, false, false, false, "http://www.example.com/marker/icons/B.png");
               }           
            });
        });
```

Just put an `if statement` inside inside the `$.get` and do the `create_marker` based on the result

Comment: Damn, so easy! Thanks!